# thousands separator in DevExpress GridView

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

How to do thousands separator in DevExpress GridView? The data is bound to the sqlserver table .

```
ASPxGridVendor2.DataSource = Session("DSGrid13")

ASPxGridVendor2.DataBind()
```

Comment: Actually it's not clear at all what you want to separate. https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: i have some numerical data like 1000000000 in that i want thousand seperator like this 100 000 000 000

Comment: i have this code in windows forms but it is not working in asp gridview the code as follows     For S = 0 To dgvReport1.Columns.Count - 1
                           
                Dim strcol As String = dgvReport1.Columns(S).FieldName
                If dgvReport1.Columns(S).ColumnType.Name.ToString = "Decimal" Then
                    dgvReport1.Columns(S).DisplayFormat.FormatType = FormatType.Numeric
                    dgvReport1.Columns(S).DisplayFormat.FormatString = "n2"

                End If
            Next

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxEditorsEditPropertiesBase_DisplayFormatStringtopic) for documentation and [here](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q368793.aspx?searchtext=format%20decimal%20grid) for question on fromatString of the Grid

**Update**

Look at [this sample](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/DataBinding/XPOLargeDB.aspx)'s code. there is a method in the cs code that do what I think you want to do. look for method

```
 protected void grid_CustomColumnDisplayText(object sender, ASPxGridViewColumnDisplayTextEventArgs e)
```

Comment: k but my data is coming from database it is not custom columns how to change it to thousand seperators for numerics in all columns

Comment: you set the displayformat in the view where you define your <dx:ASPxGridView ... />. I also updated the answer.

Comment: the displayformat property is not visible in the grid where it want to write correctly

Comment: i have this code in windows forms but it is not working in asp gridview the code as follows

Comment: For S = 0 To dgvReport1.Columns.Count - 1
                           
                Dim strcol As String = dgvReport1.Columns(S).FieldName
                If dgvReport1.Columns(S).ColumnType.Name.ToString = "Decimal" Then
                    dgvReport1.Columns(S).DisplayFormat.FormatType = FormatType.Numeric
                    dgvReport1.Columns(S).DisplayFormat.FormatString = "n2"

                End If
            Next

Comment: <dx:GridViewDataSpinEditColumn FieldName="InvoiceBrackets" VisibleIndex="0">
                        <PropertiesSpinEdit DisplayFormatString="n" ></PropertiesSpinEdit>
                        </dx:GridViewDataSpinEditColumn>

Comment: but i dont want precision in some of the columns what can i do like 10 000.00 i want only 10 000